# Generar números aleatorios con decimales Python

Tags: python

Buenos días a todos, me ha surgido una duda, y es que quiero generar en python números decimales aleatorios, es decir, por ejemplo, con este numpy puedo obtener 9 números decimales ordenados del 0 al 2

```
linspace( 0, 2, 9 )
array([ 0.  ,  0.25,  0.5 ,  0.75,  1.  ,  1.25,  1.5 ,  1.75,  2.  ])
```

Lo que yo quiero es que me de 9 números al azar entre 0 y 2, por ejemplo:

```
array([ 1.51423  ,  1.1111,  0.253 ,  0.2477,  1.154  ,  1.512,  1.4813 ,  0.24,  1.014  ])
```

Muchas gracias y saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el paquete random de NumPy encontramos varias funciones para generar datos aleatorios de manera sencilla. Prueba con:

```
np.random.rand(9)*2
```

Con np.random.rand(9) calculas un array de 9 posiciones con números aleatorios entre 0 y 1. Al multiplicarlo por 2 ya tienes los 9 números aleatorios entre 0 y 2.

Fuente: https://pybonacci.es/2013/01/11/numeros-aleatorios-en-python-con-numpy-y-scipy/

Comment: ¿Y si yo quiero hacer un rango que no sea de 0 a 2, si no de -1 a 5? Muchas gracias

Comment: Lo multiplicas por 6 y le restas 1

Comment: Muchísimas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Para generar un número seudo-aleatorio, se puede utilizar el módulo [random](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html).

El método [`random.uniform( a, b )`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.uniform) devuelve un número en coma flotante entre `a` y `b` (`b` puede o no estar incluido dependiendo de la precisión al redondear).

```
import random

desde = 0
hasta = 2
cantidad = 9

numeros = [random.uniform(desde,hasta) for x in range(cantidad)]

print(numeros)
```

Ejemplo de salida:

> [0.2618728214067698, 1.4874467324296865, 0.4022725782242256, 1.8055130809765294, 0.22787210237793887, 1.7454690494958975, 0.350325549798689, 1.4873421147411126, 0.10762784958857785]

http://rextester.com/AKMEPD38034

Answer (score 0):

Una función muy útil que puedes usar:

```
import random
def gen_numeros(minimo,maximo,cantidad):
    return [random.uniform(minimo,maximo) for i in range(0,cantidad)]

gen_numeros(0,10,3)

Out[1]: 
[3.5385240085580802, 4.922441452126823, 3.4168462603531147]
```

Comment: Hola, una pregunta, y como hago para incluir sí o sí, el número inicial y el final. Redondearlo con dos decimales será con la función round